# Compute the sum of and array accounting for overflow in macro assembly (simplified version)

Tags: assembly, avr

Hi i'm having difficulty with this program. I'm literally stuck and can't look at it anymore, can anyone help ... walk through my solution.

Here is the problem 
Write a program that computes the sum of an array x:
s = x0 + x1 + ... + xn left to right, paying attention to a possible overﬂow.

The initial data are placed as follows:
    location variable type

```
location = 2, variable n= size of the array n ≤ 8, type = unsigned integer.

location = 3 variable = x0,x1,...,xn type = array of integers
```

The result is an array of two integers. The ﬁrst one, v, should be the value 0, if there was no overﬂow, and −1 if there was, and the second one is the computed sum s. The value of s in the case when there has been an overﬂow during the computation must be 0.

Here is my code:

```
run myprog
asect 2
n:  dc  4 # replace 4 by your choice of n for testing
x:  dc  1,100,2,3 # replace numbers by your choice for testing


asect    20

res:
v:  ds  1
s:  ds  1
myprog:
ldi r0, x # r0 -> x array of unsigned int

ldi r1, n # r1 -> n 
ld  r1, r1 # r1 initial value loaded into r1 for computation = 4 for counter

do
    ld  r0, r2 # r2 is current element 1
    save    r0 # adrress of pointer saved  and reg is free
        save    r1 # adrress of counter saved  and reg is free

    ldi r3, s # r3 points to location of  sum
    st  r3, r3 # incorrect code here the value of r3 is wrong ???

    if
        add r2, r3 # add current element to sum result in r3
    is vs            # overflow set
        ldi r3, -1
        break
    fi


        restore r1 # value of r1 restored back to counter value
    restore r0 # value of r0 restored array pointer back 

    inc     r0  # r0->next element
    dec r1
until z

  # at this point 'v' and 's' have the answer
ldi   r0,res
halt
end
```

Comment: Here is my error code: Your solution has now been tested.
One of the tests performed on your solution revealed the following error:
14   result:       dc       0,21

ERROR: Line above differs from correct solution:

   result:          dc       0,-41

Initial data follows [start address 0x02 ]:

  data:            dc       2,-9,-32,0,0,0,0,0,0  # (struct int(array int 8))

Cocomaro

Comment: Try to incorporate your comment into your question. It surely does improve the quality of your question. (After that, delete it.)

Comment: What architecture is this?  Please tag it appropriately.

Comment: Because it's obviously not x86 code (I'm guessing AVR?), you stand a good chance of attracting an answer from enthusiasts as soon as you add the tag for the appropriate CPU.